# Condition for an element in Ext be zero

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Consider an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ and two objects $A,B$ of $\mathcal{A}$. It is straightforward that an element $\eta \in \text{Ext}^{1}(A,B)$ of the form $0 \to B \xrightarrow{f} X \xrightarrow{g} A \to 0$ is zero in $\text{Ext}^{1}(A,B)$ if and only if $g$ has a right inverse, which is equivalent to say that $f$ has a left inverse.

**Question:** If we take $n > 1$ and consider an element $\eta \in \text{Ext}^{n}(A,B)$ of the form $0 \to B \xrightarrow{f} X_{n} \to \cdots \to X_{1} \xrightarrow{g} A \to 0$, is it true that $\eta$ is zero $\text{Ext}^{n}(A,B)$ if and only if $g$ has a right inverse (or $f$ has a left inverse)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, consider the exact sequence
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times2}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times2}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times1}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to0$$
of abelian groups.

Comment: That is a nice example, thank you! However, it is true that if $f$ has a left inverse, or $g$ has a right inverse, then $\eta$ is zero in $\text{Ext}^{n}(A,B)$, since in this case we can write $\eta$ as a splicing of an element in $\text{Ext}^{n-1}(A,C)$ or $\text{Ext}^{n-1}(C,B)$ (for some C) together with the zero element of some $\text{Ext}^{1}(?,?)$, and the splicing operation is bilinear, right?

Comment: @Robert Yes, that’s right.